# Is a local martingale which is nonnegative at a deterministic time, nonnegative.

Tags: stochastic-processes

Assume $M$ is a continuous, local martingale s.t. for a single given $T$ we have $M(T)\geq 0$ and $P(M(T)>0)>0$. Can we then deduce $M(t)\geq 0$ for $t\leq T$?

I'm trying to use the good old Fatou trick showing a nonnegative local martingale is a supermartingale, but I only have a single point of non-negativity as above.

Thanks.

Comment: No. See Example 1 [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_martingale) and flip the signs.